# How to correctly integrate the following equation (Laplace Equation) twice

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, gauss-law, integration

I want to solve the Laplace equation and prove the potential formula for a point charge. I selected spherical coordinates to reduce the number of dimensions in the equations ending up with:

$$\Delta\Phi(r)=\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial r}\right)=0\quad\text{for }r\neq0$$

I tried double integration with the different methods, yet I did not manage to get the correct formula for the Potential.

Could someone display how to solve this equation by taking the integration twice over $r$? I will appreciate it if the answer was very detailed as I need to enhance my skills in integrations. My first approach was integrating it by parts which did not work.

Eventually what should be proved is that by integrating twice the potential formula is:

$$\Phi(r)=-\frac C r+D$$

Where $C$ and $D$ are constants produced by the integration.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I will use it from now on to write further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Can you deduce from
$$\Delta\Phi(r)=\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial r}\right)=0\quad\text{for }r\neq0$$
that $$r^2 \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial r}=c\,,\tag{*}$$i.e. that the expression on the left-hand side of Equation (*) does nor depend on $r$?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use partial derivatives ($\partial$) because the potential depends only on $r$, so replace them with $\text{d}$, i.e. derivatives, so that:

$$\Delta\Phi(r)=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\text{d}\Phi}{\text{d}r}\left(r^2\frac{\text{d}\Phi}{\text{d} r}\right)=0$$

Algebraically 'develop' the middle term using the product rule, which will give you a second order derivative ($\frac{{d}^2\Phi}{\text{d}r^2}$).

Now substitute:
$$\frac{\text{d}\Phi}{\text{d}r}=u$$

This will give you a first order DE, in  $\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}r}$, which can be integrated.

Back-substitution will then allow the second integration.